# How to create peer to peer topology for apache geode

Tags: java, geode

Below is my cluster configuration.

Cache 1 running on 1st JVM

```
Properties properties = new Properties();        
properties.setProperty("mcast-address", "224.0.0.0");
properties.setProperty("mcast-port", "0");
// This line is commented. Need to know if locator is required for peer to peer configuration.
//properties.setProperty("locators", "localhost[13489]");

CacheFactory cacheFactory = new CacheFactory(properties);

// ...

Cache cache = cacheFactory.create();
RegionFactory<String, Person> regionFactory = cache.createRegionFactory();
Region<String, Person> region = regionFactory.create("Person");
Person person = new Person(firstName, lastName);
region.put(person.getFirstName(), person);
```

Cache 2 running on 2nd JVM (or another IP)

```
Properties properties = new Properties();        
properties.setProperty("mcast-address", "224.0.0.0");
properties.setProperty("mcast-port", "0");
// This line is commented. Need to know if locator is required for peer to peer configuration.
//properties.setProperty("locators", "localhost[13489]");

CacheFactory cacheFactory = new CacheFactory(properties);

Cache cache = cacheFactory.create();
RegionFactory<String, Person> regionFactory = cache.createRegionFactory();
Region<String, Person> region = regionFactory.create("Person");
Person person = region.get(firstName);
```

The output of the above line i.e person retrieved from `region.get()` is `null`.

The question is: Is this the right configuration for peer to peer configuration?

Can you please suggest an example for creating a peer to peer cluster for Apache geode using a programmatic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to configure the list of `locators` used by the members so they can "see" each other, locators are mandatory even when using a peer to peer topology. Please have a look at [Peer-to-Peer](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/110/topologies_and_comm/p2p_configuration/chapter_overview.html) Configuration for further details.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks.. For peer to peer  / client -server topology locator is required.